# Existem alguma forma de importar um projeto no Android Studio solucionando as dependências automaticamente?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho tido dificuldades frequentes na importação de projetos no Android Studio. Sempre que faço uma nova importação, a IDE aponta várias dependências que não são satisfeitas e tenho que solucioná-las manualmente, tornando a importação sempre lenta demais.

Alguém tem uma dica de como configurar o Android Studio para solucionar pelo menos parte das dependências automaticamente.

Comment: Sues projetos utilizam o Gradle? Pois o gradle deveria cuidar das importações de dependências automaticamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como @LeoSantana sugeriu, utilize o Gradle, ele é um "automatizador de build".

Recomendo esse link: https://www.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867, curso de gradle para Android, feito pelo Udacity.

[EDIT]
Para saber as dependências que podem ser acrescentadas, pesquise aqui: https://plugins.gradle.org

Comment: Antes de mais nada bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Cuidado com as respostas, isso caberia como um comentário. Esses tipos de respostas deixa com votos negativos. Recomendo que faça um tour no StackOverflow http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Danilo obrigado, sobre a resposta é que não podia comentar até então.

Comment: não posso ainda, mas já entendi sua sugestão. Valeu!